# Efficient algorithm for finding the right elements combinations

Tags: algorithm, loops

The problem is the following:

1) Total load is given as input

2) Number of steps over which the load is divided is also given as input

3) Each step can have different discrete number of elements, which is multiple of 3 for example (i.e. 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 elements ...).

4) Elements are given as input.

5) Acceptable solutions are within a certain range "EPSILON" from the total load (equal to total load or greater but within certain margin, for example up to +2)

Example:

- Total load: 50
- Number of steps: 4
- Allowed elements that can be used are: 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 4
- Acceptable margin: +2 (i.e. total load between 50 and 52).
- Example of solutions are:

For simplicity here, each step has uniform elements, although we can have different elements in the same step (but should be grouped into 3, i.e. we can have 3 elements of 1, and 3 other elements of 2, in the same step, so total of 9).

Solution 1: total of 51

- Step 1: 3 Elements of 4 (So total of 12), (this step can be for example 3 elements of 3, and 3 elements of 1, i.e. 3 x 3 + 3 x 1).
- Step 2: 3 Elements of 4 (total of 12),
- Step 3: 9 Elements of 1.5 (total of 13.5),
- Step 4: 9 Elements of 1.5 (total of 13.5),

Solution 2: total of 51

- Step 1: 3 Elements of 4 (total of 12)
- Step 2: 3 Elements of 4 (total of 12)
- Step 3: 6 Elements of 2 (total of 12)
- Step 4: 15 Elements of 1 (total of 15)

The code that I used takes the above input, and writes another code depending on the number of steps.

The second code basically loops over the number of steps (loops inside each other's) and checks for all the possible elements combinations.

Example of loops for 2 steps solution:

Code:

```
For NumberofElementsA = 3 To 18 Step 3
'''''18 here is the maximum number of elements per step, since I cannot let it go to infinity, so I need to define a maximum for elemnt
    For  NumberofElementsB = 3 To 18 Step 3
        For AllowedElementsA = 1 To 6
           For AllowedElementsB = AllowedElementsA To 6
             ''''Allowed elements in this example were 6: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 4]

                LoadDifference = -TotalLoad + NumberofElementsA * ElementsArray(AllowedElementsA)  + NumberofElementsB * ElementsArray(AllowedElementsB) 

           ''''basically it just multiplies the number of elements (here 3, 6, 9, ... to 18) to the value of the element (0.5, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 4) in each loop and subtracts the total load.

                If LoadDifference  <= 2 And LoadDifference  >= 0

                '''Solution OK

                End If
            Next AllowedElementsB 
        Next AllowedElementsA 
    Next NumberofElementsB 
Next NumberofElementsA
```

So basically the code loops over all the possible number of elements and possible elements values, and checks each result.

Is there an algorithm that solves in a more efficient way the above problem ? Other than looping over all possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're restricted to groups of 3, this transforms immediately to a problem with all weights tripled:

```
1.5, 3, 4.5, 7.5, 9, 12
```

Your range is a target value +2, or within 1 either way from the midpoint of that range (51 +- 1).

Since you've listed no requirement on balancing step loads, this is now an instance of the target sum problem -- with a little processing before and after the central solution.

Comment: Thanks Prune.

Actually yes steps should be balanced (but not necessarily 100%, since sometimes there are no solutions that are completely balanced), so the best solution is the one with the minimum standard deviation between the total loads of steps.

My question: is there a better way other than trying all elements values while increasing the number of elements in each iteration, and checking the solution ?

Comment: Of course: you're now trying to optimize for a step sum of total_sum / 4 ... again, a known algorithm.  Given a total sum, you have a short job of optimizing the error function (which you have yet to define) for the four differences.

Comment: Appreciate your support @prune , could you please share a link that discusses this algorithm ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you want a link to generic optimization or to "target sum", but easy is a straightforward browser search.